# ColorBox centers in the middle of the page and not in the middle of pageview

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I am using colorbox for quite a while and its working perfectly in all kind of websites.
I have encountered a website that is really really long, and when i open the colorbox, it will open in the middle of it and not in the middle of my page view.

What can affect this???

thank you!!!!

Comment: can you show us a screenshot or so??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. This site didn't have any DOCTYPE.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely conflicting css on the site - not the length of the page.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this.

```
$.colorbox({
                width: "600px", height: "500px", inline: false, overlayClose: false, escKey: true, iframe: true,
                onComplete: function () {
                    $('#colorbox').removeAttr('top');//test
                    $('#colorbox').css('top', '100px');//test
                    $('#colorbox').removeAttr('display');//test
                    $('#colorbox').css('display', 'block');//test
                },
                onLoad: function () {
                    $('#colorbox').removeAttr('display');//test
                    $('#colorbox').css('display', 'none');//test
                },
            });
```

Comment: Please explain it properly.